# Flex/Bison parser recognizes "(" differently from "( "

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to write a simple parser of a toy language using flex and bison, it basically only supports variables and arithmetic functions.

Currently I'm facing a weird problem where statements with an open parenthesis and a space between the next token work differently from statements with an open parenthesis and no space between the next token, specifically I'm trying to recognize the following program.

```
var b: int
begin
b <- (4)
end
```

Trying to do so fails with syntax error at line 3, however if I add a space between 4 and (, the program is recognized correctly.

My parser.lex file is as follows.

```
%{
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
%}

LETTR   [a-zA-Z]
DIGIT   [0-9]
BIN     [0-1] 
SIMB   [$|_]
WHITESPACE [ \t\r]+ 

%%
WHITESPACE  { }
"\n"    {yylineno++;}
"begin"  {return BEGN;}
"if"     {return IF;}
"ifelse" {return IFELSE;}
"while"  {return WHILE;}
"end"                           {return END;}
"var"             {return VAR;}
"read"            {return READ;}
"print"           {return PRINT;}
"int"             {return INT;}
"float"           {return FLOAT;}
"<-"                            {return ASSIGN;}
({SIMB}|{LETTR})({LETTR}|{DIGIT}|{SIMB})*  {yylval.id=(char*)malloc(strlen(yytext)+1); strcpy(yylval.id, yytext); return ID;} /* Identificador */
({DIGIT})({DIGIT})*   {return NUMINT;}   /*Entero*/
({DIGIT})*.({DIGIT})({DIGIT})*     {return NUMFLOAT;} /*Punto Flotante*/
";"                             {return SEMICOLON;}
":"               {return COLON;}
"+"                             {return PLUS;}
"-"                             {return MINUS;}
"*"                             {return MULT;}
"/"                             {return DIVIDE;}
"<"                             {return LESSTHAN;}
">"                             {return GREATTHAN;}
"="                             {return EQUALS;}
"<="                            {return LESSEQUALS;}
">="                            {return GREATEQUALS;}
"~"               {return NEGSIGN;}
"("                             {return LEFTP;}
")"                             {return RIGHTP;}
.                 { }
%%
```

And my parser.y file is as follows:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
FILE extern *yyin;
char extern *yytext;
int yylineno;
int yylex();
int yyerror(char const * s);
void addToTable(char * var);
void initTable();
void checkVar();
void printTable();


%}
%union{
  char *id;
}
%token <id > ID
%token BEGN IF IFELSE WHILE END VAR ASSIGN LEFTP RIGHTP INT FLOAT SEMICOLON COLON PLUS MINUS 
MULT DIVIDE LESSTHAN GREATTHAN EQUALS LESSEQUALS GREATEQUALS NUMINT NUMFLOAT READ PRINT NEGSIGN
%start prog


%%

prog: opt_decls BEGN opt_stmts END {printf("Valid program!\n"); printTable(); return 0;}

opt_decls: decls
          | /* empty */
;

decls : dec SEMICOLON decls
      | dec
;

dec : VAR ID COLON tipo { addToTable($2);}
;

tipo : INT 
     | FLOAT
;

stmt : ID ASSIGN expr {checkVar($1);}
     | IF LEFTP expression RIGHTP stmt
     | IFELSE LEFTP expression RIGHTP stmt stmt
     | WHILE LEFTP expression RIGHTP stmt
     | READ ID {checkVar($2);}
     | PRINT expr
     | BEGN opt_stmts END
;

opt_stmts : stmt_lst
          | /*empty*/
;

stmt_lst : stmt SEMICOLON stmt_lst
          | stmt
;

expression : expr
           | expr relop expr
;

expr : expr PLUS term
     | expr MINUS term
     | sign term
     | term  

term : term MULT factor
     | term DIVIDE factor
     | factor
; 

factor : LEFTP expr RIGHTP 
       | ID {checkVar($1);}
       | NUMINT
       | NUMFLOAT
;

relop : LESSTHAN 
      | GREATTHAN 
      | EQUALS 
      | LESSEQUALS 
      | GREATEQUALS 
;

sign : NEGSIGN
;

%%
char symbolTable [100][50];

int yyerror(char const * s) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s at line: %d while reading %s\n", s, yylineno, yytext);
}

void printTable(){
  printf("Symbol table:\n");
  int i; 
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if (strcmp(symbolTable[i], "") != 0){
      printf("%s\n", symbolTable[i]);
    }
  }
}

void addToTable(char *var){
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if (strcmp(symbolTable[i], "") == 0){
      strcpy(symbolTable[i], var);
      break;    
    }
  }
}

void initTable(){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    strcpy(symbolTable[i], "");
  }
}

void checkVar(char * var){
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if (strcmp(symbolTable[i], var) == 0){
      return;
    } 
  }
  char errorMsg [255];
  sprintf(errorMsg, "Variable %s was not initialized", var);
  yyerror(errorMsg);
  exit(-1);
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  initTable();  
  if (argc == 1)
        printf("Input file not found.\n");
        else{
            yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
      yyparse();
        } 

  fclose(yyin);
}
```

I am honestly stumped as to what might cause this.

I am running the program with the following command (using Ubuntu 16.04)

```
flex parser.lex
bison -d parser.y
gcc lex.yy.c parser.tab.c -lfl
./a.out p3.txt
```

Where p3.txt is a text file with the program to be parsed.

Comment: Can't explain that. You will have to trace the tokens and reductions. It is simpler and more readable to just return `*yytext` for all those single-character tokens, and use them literally in the grammar, e.g. `'('`. That way also illegal characters become syntax errors, which allows better error-recovery, by *yacc* rather than simply ignoring it. The `.` in the NUMFLOAT rule needs to be quoted. Most expression grammars split up `factor` into a lower `primary` level, and you have `sign TERM` at the wrong level, it should be in the missing `primary` level, and it should be `sign primary`.

Comment: And `stmnt_list` should be left-recursive, not right-recursive, for LR parsing.

Comment: Ok, after adding quotes between the . in NUMFLOAT the problem went away, do you have any idea of what might've caused that?

Comment: . means any character other than \n, so space also considered

Comment: `.` matches any character unless you quote it, so it matched the space, and then the following digit made the parser see `( NUMFLOAT NUMINT ...`. The NUMFLOAT rule is wrong anyway if it matches only `.`. It should insist on at least one digit somewhere, usually after the decimal point: `{DIGIT}*"."{DIGIT}+`.